# How to upload create-react-app production build with multi-tenant?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, create-react-app, multi-tenant

I am building an app with multi-tenant which serve more than one client, currently, I have to build all the instance one by one and also have to upload all the build one by one, it's also time-consuming.

Here is what I do before creating a build,

- Change production API Url and Client instance(like "abc","cde","efg")
- Set homepage in package.json like "/abc","/cde","/efg"
- `<BrowserRouter basename={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}`}>`, PUBLIC_URL is same as "/abc" or "/cde" etc

Now, My domain name is like "example.com" or "1**.1**.2*.*"

So my app accessible by example.com/abc,example.com/cde etc, In the server there are directories for all the instances ("abc","cde" etc).

Now I want to remove all the directories from the server and want to upload a single build for all instead of creating a separate build for all the instances.

Any comments/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to the problem statement you have given

**Option 1**

In this case, I assume that your tenant's already are aware of the URL structure and they are used to this format.

In your case, you might have to landing page component that takes route segment which we use to identify the tenant.

Example Route
`<Route path="/auth/:id" component={AuthComponent} />`

In the componentDidMount method, you will examine the tenant name and make an API call to get the tenant information by name. On receipt of the data, you will store the values in a redux store or any other mode you would opt-in.

```
   const tenantName=undefined;
    if (undefined !== this.props.match.params && null != this.props.match.params) {
        tenantName = this.props.match.params.id;
// make the api call to get the tenant info
} else {
 //The tenant name is not identified, ask the user to supply the tenant name in the URL
}
```

The redirection to the home page is made with the tenant context setup based on the response from the API call.

From now on, all your components can use the tenant context information from the redux / any store so that the pages are displaying the data based on the set tenant context.

Assuming that you do not have tenant specific pages, this approach will be fine

**Option 2**

In this option, allow the user to choose a tenant from the login page and then perform the login, post the login, the tenant context will be available which can be set in the redux store and used throughout as explained above.

This can be used when your tenant's have their company codes known and got used to this.

**Option 3**

Allow the end user to login and post successful login, if the user has access to a single tenant, you can automatically setup the tenant context and then continue using the application.

In case the end user has access to multiple tenant's, show a dropdown of the list of tenant's that they have access to. This will be done after the login is successful so that the user selects the tenant for which they want to work and they are able to access the pages / functionality.

This option is a good one that i would vouch for as this gives you better control and also the user has a good UX with the application.